# Looping Through AutoFilters that Frequently Change

Tags: vba, loops, excel, autofilter

I have a dataset that is going to be changing daily. I want to filter the data based on the company name - "Company 1", "Company 2", "Company 3", etc. And then run another sub. I currently do (just the filtering) with the following code.

```
Sub StackOverflowQuestion()
    Editing_Sheet.Range("$A$1:$AH$1669").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "Company 1"
    Editing_Sheet.Range("$A$1:$AH$1669").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "Company 2"
    Editing_Sheet.Range("$A$1:$AH$1669").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "Company 3"
    Editing_Sheet.Range("$A$1:$AH$1669").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "Company 4"
    Editing_Sheet.Range("$A$1:$AH$1669").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        "Company 5"
End Sub
```

But as the data (including the company names) is constantly changing - e.g. it will go all the way up to "Company 20", exclude the odd numbered companies, have names that are different altogether like "New company name 45", etc. It makes it difficult to have consistent code that does it all at the click of the button.

I tried the following code (just to see if I was on the right track, arbitrarily using "50") to loop through all the autofilter options

```
Sub LoopThroughAuto
    For i = 1 to 50
    Editing_Sheet.Range("$A$1:$AH$1669").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        i
next i
```

But that didn't work. Is there anyway to loop through all the the autofilter options and then filter them?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Dictionary` object allows you to create a list of all unique entries in `Column A`. Next, you can loop over the unique entries, filtering by each one. NOTE: In my code below, I've employed the `CurrentRegion` property of `A1`. This property assume that data is contiguous, without any empty rows or columns. Update it if necessary.

```
Sub StackOverflowQuestion()
    Dim rngCompanyNames As Range
    Dim oDictionary As Object
    Dim cel As Range

    Set oDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set rngCompanyNames = Intersect(Editing_Sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, Editing_Sheet.Columns(1))

    For Each cel In rngCompanyNames
        If oDictionary.exists(cel.Value) Then
            'Do nothing for now
        Else
            oDictionary.Add cel.Value, 0
        End If
    Next cel

    For Each oKey In oDictionary.keys
        Editing_Sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=CStr(oKey)
        'RUN WHATEVER CODE YOU NEED TO RUN NOW
    Next oKey
End Sub
```

Comment: If I need to change the column that has the list of company names ex column C, Do I just need to change the "A1"s to "C1"? Or also change the value within the Columns to Columns(3)?

Comment: @New2VBA To create the dictionary object with the unique entries, you'd only have to change `Columns(3)` in the `Set rngCompanyNames...` line. The `CurrentRegion` property, being set against `Range(A1)` checks all cells adjacent to `A1` without breaks, so it wouldn't make a difference to change it. Let me know if that's clear enough.

Comment: For some reason I can only get it to work when I'm trying to filter through the unique values within the A column. I've tried to switch it to others (as you've described above) and all it does is go blank under the headings

Comment: Ah figured it out. Had to change the field number in the editing_sheet.range part

Comment: Any reason why it wouldn't recognize cells with the value "#NA"? It loops and filters through all of the values except that one.